# How do I programmatically render a form, other than the default form?

Tags: forms, 8

In a preprocess function we can use this code to render the default form.

```
$default_form = \Drupal::config('contact.settings')->get('default_form');
$entity = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('contact_form')->load($default_form);

$message = \Drupal::entityManager()
   ->getStorage('contact_message')
   ->create(array('contact_form' => $entity->id(),
));

$form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($message);
```

How do we render another form? I have tried `$my_form = \Drupal::config('contact.settings')->get('my_form_id');` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contact form?

your_form_id is the form, you don't have to load a setting for that. If you know what contact form you want to display, just replace $default_form with your form_id and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Berdir ! Just one mention: I created a custom form with the machine name `product_information`. It seems that you sould pass the machine name of the bundle entity, rather than the form id like in `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`.

Comment: The code you shared is about *contact forms*, which are config entities created in the UI. If product_information would be such a form, you'd just write $default_form = 'product_information'. If you have a custom form, then that's completely different. You just need something like this: \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm'). Class name, not form id.